# Share and update data using Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that calls an API like so:

```
app.service("GetDivision", ["$http", function($http){

  this.division = function(divisionNumber){
    return $http.post("/api/league", {division:divisionNumber}).success(function(data){
      return data;
    });
  }

}]);
```

I then have 2 (or more) controllers that call the service: `GetDivision.division(number);`

Now, controller A loads the data it gets from the service and displays it in an HTML table or something similar. Controller B has functionality that updates the data in the database. When this happens, I need to update the HTML produced from controller A.

So I think I need to do one of the follow but can't understand how to do either:

- When controller B updates the data, tell controller A to make a new request to the service for the updated data.
- When controller B updates the data, also update a variable which contains the data in the service. Controller A then watches for the variable change in the service and the HTML is updated.

Comment: Try simply with like $state.go('route.controllerA',{}, {reload: true});if you use ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of handling this.

The easiest way is to `$rootScope.$broadcast(...)` when Controller B updates the service data. Everywhere else you listen on `$scope.$on(...)` for that change event, and update the data.

This approach isn't the best, because you end up with code listening for broadcasts coming from unknown locations in the source code. Making it more difficult to maintain.

The better approach is to use proper scope hierarchy.

A parent directive can call `$scope.$broadcast(...)` to send messages to all child directives. So you would create a directive B that contains directive A. Directive A can then listen for changes from directive B.

Sometimes that's not a possible approach and directive B *must* be a child of directive A. In that case, you use the `require` feature of a directive. This will inject the controller from A into the directive B. When you make a change you call a method of controller A to notify it of the change.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand. Could you show an example?

Comment: @Coop to better explain would be more than an answer. I think this is a good topic for a blog post. I'll work on that today.

Comment: Aah I've had more of a play around with the $broadcast method and got it working. Thanks for your solutions.